# Radiobutton instance has no attibute 'variable

Tags: tkinter, radiobuttonfor

I'm trying to give the user a set of choices using radio buttons.  When I click on the "Get Data Type" button, Python returns "AttributeError: Radiobutton instance has no attribute 'variable'.  Clearly it does, but refuses to see it (them):

```
class DataType:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = LabelFrame(master, text = 'Data Type')
        frame.pack()

        data_contents = StringVar()

        self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(frame,
                     text="Fixed Data",
                     variable = data_contents,
                     value = 'fixed')
        self.radiobutton.pack()

        self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(frame,
                     text="Random Data",
                     variable = data_contents,
                     value = 'random')
        self.radiobutton.pack()

        self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(frame,
                     text="All 1's",
                     variable = data_contents,
                     value = '1s')
        self.radiobutton.pack()

        self.radiobutton = Radiobutton(frame,
                     text="All 0's",
                     variable = data_contents,
                     value = '0s')
        self.radiobutton.pack()


        data_contents.set(self.radiobutton)
        self.printdata = Button(frame,
                         text="What data?",
                         command=self.write_data)
        self.printdata.pack()

    def write_data(self):
        print (self.radiobutton.variable)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding tkinter options. When you specify an attribute like `variable=data_contents`, it does not become an attribute of the object. Instead, it is a widget configuration option.

To access the value of the `variable` configuration option you need to use one of the following:

```
self.radiobutton.cget("variable")
self.radiobutton["variable"]
```

Note: you are headed down the wrong path with this question. You don't need to get the variable since you control what the variable is. The variable should be an instance attribute that you can call the `get()` method on:

```
...
self.data_contents = StringVar()
...
def write_data(self):
    print(self.data_contents.get())
```

Comment: Ok.  Thank you.  So your answer begs the question: What widget configuration option is `variable`?  What is being configured when I set `variable=data_contents`?

Comment: When I add either of these: `self.radiobutton.cget("variable")` or `self.radiobutton["variable"]`, I get `PY_VAR0`

Comment: @MrPacket: I'm not sure I understand your question. The `variable` option of the widget is being set when you do `variable=data_contents`. It is not an instance attribute, it's a configuration option.

Comment: `self.radiobutton["variable"].get()` gives the following: `AttributeError '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: I got it.  I actually want to access the `value` attribute. `self.radiobutton.cget("value")` did the trick.  Thank you!!

Comment: So, rather than open a new question, I thought it best to bring this question to you, since you have already seen the code.  I am now able to get the `value`, but the program returns `0s` no matter which radio button is selected.  I suspect the program returns `0s` because it is the last in the list.  I do not understand how to allow the user to select one of the radio button options and have the program return the option that was selected.

Comment: In your code, you reuse `self.radiobutton` several times to mean several widgets; when you get the value it will always get the value of just one radiobutton. To get the selected value, you should make the associated variable an instance attribute (eg: `self.data_contents = StringVar()`) and then call get on that variable (eg: `self.data_contents.get()`)

Comment: Thanks. It worked.  I don't exactly know why, and what the difference is.  Clearly, I need to study and learn more.  Can you recommend a book for learning TkInter?